# Permutations of 2D points

Tags: c++, c++11

I would like to explore all the permutation of a 2d points (x, y coordinates in a 2D-Array)
My 2d point struct is:

```
struct pos_t {
    int x; int y; 
    pos_t(){x = 0 ; y = 0;} 
    pos_t(int X, int Y){x=X; y=Y;}
    pos_t(pos_t const & r) {x = r.x; y=r.y;}
    pos_t& operator=(pos_t const & r) {x = r.x; y=r.y; return *this;}
    bool operator < ( pos_t& p2)
    {
        return (x+y) < (p2.x+p2.y);
    }
    friend ostream& operator << (ostream &o, const pos_t& p)
    {
        return o << "(" << p.x << "," << p.y << ")";
    }
};
```

Using a vector of pos_t call treasurePos (`vector<pos_t>`), i use the code below to iterate other the different permutation and display each.

```
    do {
        copy(begin(treasurePos), end(treasurePos), ostream_iterator<pos_t>(cout, " -> "));
        cout << endl;
    } while ( std::next_permutation(begin(treasurePos),end(treasurePos)) );
```

But with the following pos_t element in my vector : (0,2) and (1,0)
I get only one permutation: `(0,2) -> (1,0) ->`

I expected to have:

```
(0,2) -> (1,0) -> 
(1,0) -> (0,2) ->
```

Another example, with 4 points where i get only 2 permutatins:

```
(1,3) -> (2,2) -> (3,0) -> (3,1) -> 
(1,3) -> (2,2) -> (3,1) -> (3,0) ->
```

Have you an idea ?

Answer (score 5):

`next_permutation` is `false` when the new permutation isn't lexicographically greater than the old.

Since your ordering says that `(1,0)` is less than `(0,2)`, the sequence `{(1,0), (0,2)}` is lexicographically smaller than `{(0,2), (1,0)}`, and  `next_permutation` is `false` immediately.

The same reason is behind your four-point example.

If you want to go through all permutations, you should sort the sequence first.

Comment: Thanks, I reviewed your answer and found finally why even with a call to `sort` I will never get all permutation (see my answer ...), but thank you again for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Atop of molbdnil answer. To get all the permutations the initial set should be sorted. So, this should do the trick.

```
std::sort(begin(treasurePos), end(treasurePos));
do {
    copy(begin(treasurePos), end(treasurePos), ostream_iterator<pos_t>(cout, " -> "));
    cout << endl;
} while ( std::next_permutation(begin(treasurePos),end(treasurePos)) );
```

Comment: Thanks, I reviewed your answer and found finally why even with a call to sort I will never get all permutation (see my answer ...), but thank you again for your help

Answer (score 1):

Finally I found why even with a call to `sort`, I will never get all permutation (see my answer ...), but thank you again for your help.

All answers mentioning a call to `std::sort` prior to any call to `next_permutation`are correct (Thats why I up voted most of the answers). But in fact, the most important here is to noticed that the `lexicographic`order depends of the compare operator you use.

The default parameters is `bool operator < ( ... )` but with the implementation I provided (see below), (1,3) is equal to (3,1).

```
bool operator < ( pos_t& p2)
{
    return (x+y) < (p2.x+p2.y);
}
```

And thats why I will never get the permutation (i.e for N **distinct** elements, we get N!  permutations)

A correct operator to `pos_t` will be :

```
bool operator < ( pos_t const & p) const
{
  return (x < p.x) || ((x == p.x) && (y < p.y));
}
```

And now we can sort, loop and collect all permutations.

```
std::sort(begin(treasurePos), end(treasurePos));
do {
  vector<pos_t> c;
  copy(begin(treasurePos), end(treasurePos), back_inserter(c));

  copy(begin(c), end(c), ostream_iterator<pos_t>(cout, " -> "));
  cout << endl;

  treasure_order.push_back(c);

} while ( std::next_permutation(begin(treasurePos),end(treasurePos)) );

cout << "we stored " << treasure_order.size() << " path to get all the treasure (=nbTreasure! = " << fact((int)treasurePos.size()) << ")" << endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to make std::next_permutation to give all permutations your initial vector should be sorted with the same comparator before the loop.

Answer (score -1):

From [cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/next_permutation/):

> Rearranges the elements in the range [first,last) into the next lexicographically greater permutation.
>
> Different permutations can be ordered according to how they compare lexicographicaly to each other; The first such-sorted possible permutation (the one that would compare lexicographically smaller to all other permutations) is the one which has all its elements sorted in ascending order, and the largest has all its elements sorted in descending order.
>
> **If the function can determine the next higher permutation**, it rearranges the elements as such and returns true. **If that was not possible (because it is already at the largest possible permutation), it rearranges the elements according to the first permutation (sorted in ascending order) and returns false.**

So basically, if you want to make it work, the starting permutation must be the smallest one.